# How do I resolve a missing GPG key for an apt repo in Debian 12?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, gpg

I'm currently running Debian 12 and am trying to download some .deb packages for a Debian 8.7 machine that has no access to the internet. To do this, I've configured a new apt repo that targets the Debian 8.7 archive branch (Jessie). My /etc/apt/sources.list now includes:

```
deb https://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

When I run `apt update' I get a GPG missing public key.

[image]

My questions:

1. Where do I find the public key for this archived repo?
2. How do I apply this key to apt in Debian 12?

Most search results reference arcane 3rd party key servers or Ubuntu results. I'm hoping I can just find a Debian webpage that features that key, and then manually add that key to a some trusted key sources in Debian 12.

Comment: perhaps you can download the last dvd image of jessie , mount it on the right machine in loop, add a local repo from the mounted dvd and upgrade the machine or the packet that you need.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/stable/debian-archive-keyring

Comment: @IporSircer that won’t help, the Jessie keys were dropped in version 2021.1 of that package.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing a staged upgrade.  Don't do the upgrade all at once.  Granted without internet access this will be tough, but you can go from 8(Jessie) to 9(Stretch) then from 9(Stretch) to 10(Buster). and so on until you finally arrive at 12(Bookworm).  Instead of using the internet to perform the staged `dist-upgrade`s, we can use the Live CD's/USB's as the APT sources.  Note that the steps here are a "rough overview" that may require tweaking as we go:

### Preparation

1. Download the Appropriate Live Images from the [Debian CD Image Archives](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/).

   - I won't tell you which ones to download, but you're going to have to sift through a bunch of files(i.e. there are 13 point versions of stretch, each with a corresponding live image).
2. Create the image for each CD downloaded

### Working Loop

3. Use `apt-cdrom` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cdrom)) to add the images from step 2 as an apt source.

   - The first one you'll want to add is the last point release for 8(Jessie)
4. Perform any updates needed to get to the last point release of 8 (`dist-upgrade`)
5. Reboot, and fix breakages if any, keeping the 8 Apt Source CD

### Start Over With New Live CD/USB

6. Once breakages/issues are fixed, remove the 8 CD as a source. Repeat Step 3 for the 9 CD
7. Repeat step 4 for 9(Stretch)
8. Repeat Steps 5 and 6 for 9(Stretch)

Keep Looping like this through each LiveCD/USB until you reach 12(Bookworm)